# Reverse Geocoding: cannot connect to World Geocode Service

Tags: arcgis-online, reverse-geocoding

I should probably go to ESRI for help with this question, but I was hoping that someone else might have had the same problem and solved it. I'm part of a larger university and we get ArcMap as a site license. We geocode often and pay for credits on ArcGIS Online. However, when I've needed to geocode I've noticed that when I physically open the tool that only the MGRS geocoding service is available. Yet when I right click on a dbase of addresses and select the geocode option the World Geocoder shows up as available and works (if I'm signed in to ArcGIS online of course). I've been geocoding this way and it hasn't been an issue, except now I need to reverse geocode. The World geocoding service isn't showing up in the reverse geocoding tool and there no options under the right click for reverse geocode. I've tried "adding a geocoder" in the tool bar but I can't find where the World Geocode Service lives. Any ideas about how to fix this or get around the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40802) helps. It's a link on how to connect to the World Geocode Service via adding an ArcGIS Server Connection